# Using Orchard CMS how do I change the heading displayed in the list of content items

Tags: orchardcms

I have created a new module in Orchard CMS, i have a new event part that has a whole bunch of custom fields.  How do i change the heading displayed in the list of content?

Thanks

[image: Orchard CMS Content List]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to set the meta data in the Handler

```
protected override void GetItemMetadata(GetContentItemMetadataContext context)
{
    // We will set the display text, appears in content list
    var e = context.ContentItem.As<EventPart>();
    if (e != null)
    {
        context.Metadata.DisplayText = e.Name;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Rohan you legend

Answer (score 0):

You could use the ITitleAspect method:

```
public interface ITitleAspect : IContent {
    string Title { get; }
}
```

As seen in [David Hayden's fine post](http://www.davidhayden.me/blog/content-types-with-title-part-and-ititleaspect-in-orchard-1.3).